# Django ImportError looks like a loop

Tags: python, django

In my django project I have the following:

apps1/models.py: Post (model)
apps2/models.py: Blogs (model)
apps2/functions.py: get_blogs (method)

The apps1/models.py file imports the Blogs model from apps2/models.py.
The apps2/models.py file imports the get_blogs method from apps2/functions.py.
The apps2/functions.py file import the Post model from apps1/models.py.

I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError at /
cannot import name Post

Traceback
admin.autodiscover()
<in file apps1/models.py>
from apps2.models import Blogs
<in file apps2/models.py>
from apps2.functions import get_blogs
<in file apps2/functions.py>
from apps1.models import Post
```

I thought it might be that the admin.autodiscover is importing the Post model first and then through an import loop, it is trying to import it again. Although I tried changing it to:

```
from apps1.models import Post as OtherPost
```

but that didn't help. Any idea why this is happening? Is it because there is a loop now?

Comment: Just a thought: Are your models (the actual classes) two directories deep? (counting from the project root) In that case have you got app_label defined in the Meta class of each model?

Comment: No. The models are in the models.py files directly inside the app directories. None have the app_label defined.

Comment: I've just tried commenting out the admin.autodiscover() and nothing changes (the Traceback changes a little, but the error is the same and happens at the same spot (when importing Post inside the apps2/functions.py file))

Comment: Try to move the `Post` import in `apps2/functions.py` out of the file scope, to just before where you actually use it. If it then works, then you have a recursion issue.

Comment: jro: What you suggested also worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the only reason you import `Blogs` in `apps1.models` is that you have a relationship field in `Post`, how about using a lazy relationship instead? As far as I understand, those were designed specifically to deal with import loops like the one you're experiencing.

It is quite easy, instead of

```
from apps2.models import Blogs
...
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    my_blog = models.ForeignKey(Blogs)
```

you use something like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    my_blog = models.ForeignKey("apps2.Blogs")
```